# ASPX page submiting field with accent values is not working

Tags: asp.net, encoding, web-config

I cannot post the code or a URL, it is local and private.  However this is the issue:

When I submit the form on a ASPX page it has a large hidden value text with accents for French.  The accents get garbled and replaced if sent to another page, but if I submit it to itself and check the value, it maintains the accents.  Any ideas how I can fix this?

An example of a test i tried was:

worked.  Printed out: é space é

when action sent to test2.aspx value output was Ã© space Ã©

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting this in your web.config

```
<globalization 
            requestEncoding="utf-8" 
            responseEncoding="utf-8"  />
```